# Код из звёздочек

Tags: любой-язык, соревнование

Как использовать это в качестве кода?

```
**       *****  **
 **     **  ** **
  **   **   ****
   ** **    ** **
    ***     **  **
                 **
********************
*********************
```

Приветствуются оригинальные решения. Вариант с наибольшим числом голосов побеждает.

```js
function getAnswers(questionId, answer_filter, page) {
  return jQuery.ajax({
    url: '//api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/' + questionId + '/answers?page=' + page + '&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=activity&site=ru.stackoverflow&filter=' + answer_filter,
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true
  }).then(function(data) {
    if (data.has_more) {

      return getAnswers(questionId, answer_filter, page + 1).then(function(d) {
        return data.items.concat(d.items);
      })
    }
    return data.items;
  });
}

function getAuthorName(e) {
  return e.owner.display_name
}

function process(items) {

  return items.map(function(item) {
    var matched = item.body.match(/<h\d+>\s*(.+?)\s*<\/h/);
    if (matched) {
      return {
        lang: matched[1],
        count: item.score,
        link: item.share_link,
        author: getAuthorName(item)

      };
    } else {
      return {
        lang: "N/A",
        count: "N/A",
        link: item.share_link,
        author: getAuthorName(item)
      }
    }
  });
}

function sort(items) {
  return items.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.count - a.count;
  })
}

function fillTemplate(sortedItems) {
  $('#leadership').append(sortedItems.map(function(item, index) {
    return $('<tr>').append($('<td>').html(index + 1))
      .append($('<td>').html(item.author))
      .append($('<td>').html(item.lang))
      .append($('<td>').html(item.count))
      .append($('<td>').append($('<a>').attr('href', item.link).text('Link')));
  }));
  return sortedItems;
}

var QUESTION_ID = 520257,
  ANSWER_FILTER = "!4*SyY(4Kifo3Mz*lT",
  startPage = 1;
getAnswers(QUESTION_ID, ANSWER_FILTER, startPage)
  .then(process)
  .then(sort)
  .then(fillTemplate);
```

```css
#leadership {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#leadership td,
#leadership th {
  padding: 5px;
}
#leadership th {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Таблица лидеров</h1>
<table id="leadership">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Автор</th>
    <th>Язык</th>
    <th>Счет</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: а `<?php echo '***...';` можно считать использованием *в качестве кода*? )) И конвертер "пробездочек" в brainfuck можно рассматривать? И только конкретное изображение можно использовать или саму идею?

Comment: Может быть, добавить метку [код-гольф]?

Comment: @BOPOH, да, echo можно, но вряд ли это достаточно оригинально, чтобы получить плюсики. А есть какая-то идея, которая не работает на конкретном изображении?

Comment: @val, [tag:конкурс] её заменяет. У гольфа всё-таки предполагается оценка по числу символов.

Comment: А когда награждение победителей задумано?

Comment: @Grundy, сортировка по голосам же есть)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## C++

http://ideone.com/JRY307

```
struct outputter { outputter operator*(); };

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    outputter o;

    **       *****  **
     **     **  ** **
      **   **   ****
       ** **    ** **
        ***     **  **
                     **
    ********************
    *********************
    
    o;

    return 0;
}

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

string text =
    "IF you happen to have read another book about Christopher Robin, "
    "you may remember that he once had a swan (or the swan had Christopher "
    "Robin, I don't know which) and that he used to call this swan Pooh. "
    "That was a long time ago, and when we said good-bye, we took the name "
    "with us, as we didn't think the swan would want it any more. "
    "Well, when Edward Bear said that he would like an exciting name all to himself, "
    "Christopher Robin said at once, without stopping to think, that he was "
    "Winnie-the-Pooh.";

istringstream iss{ text };
auto it = istream_iterator<string>{ iss };

outputter outputter::operator*()
{
    cout << *it++ << " ";
    return *this;
}
```

---

Идея: объявим класс с оператором `*`, который будет возвращать сам объект. Таки образом, можно вызывать оператор `*` сколько угодно раз подряд.

Чтобы объект делал что-нибудь полезное, возьмём текст из Винни-Пуха (`string text = ...`), положим его в поток `iss`, и будем читать из потока итератором (`istream_iterator`) (потоковое чтение строки читает одно слово за раз, так же, как и с `cin`, поэтому мы фактически разбили текст на слова по пробелам). Каждый раз во время работы оператора `*` выведем следующее слово и продвинем итератор.

Comment: Можно обрисовать в общих чертах что тут к чему и почему работает? В `C++` знаю три с половиной оператора, но выглядит внушительно.

Comment: @Other: Добавил к ответу.

Comment: Благодарю, кое-что понятно стало, заслуженный плюс и восхищение - какую шайтан-машину люди создали!

Comment: А vector зачем? istream_iterator нельзя инкрементить?

Comment: @Qwertiy: И правда, промежуточный вектор не нужен. Инерция мышления :) Обновил ответ.

Comment: Вы не в курсе, когда получите свои законные +15? У подобных соревнований вообще подразумевается ограниченность по времени?

Comment: @edem: Хороший вопрос. Думаю, это на усмотрение автора. Хотя о идее для конкурсов хорошей идеей было бы объявление продолжительности конкурса заранее.

Comment: @edem, выдал :)

Answer (score 8):

## Clojure

```clj
'(**       *****  **
   **     **  ** **
    **   **   ****
     ** **    ** **
      ***     **  **
                   **
  ********************
  *********************)
```

А равно это... не поверите:

```clj
(** ***** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **** ** ** ** ** *** ** ** ** ******************** *********************)
```

...это **список** из **символов**, которые используются для представления *идентификаторов в коде в виде данных* (Clojure же лисп, помните?). И идентификаторы в Clojure имеют довольно безумную свободу в именовании. Да, они вполне могут состоять из звёздочек!

Если бы в начале не было кавычки, оно бы попыталось разрешить в значения идентификаторы `*****`, `**`, `********************`, `*********************`, `***` и `****`, не смогло бы (ведь их нет), и упало бы. Но можно их определить:

```clj
(let [** (fn [& args]) ; функция, принимает любое число аргументов и не делает ничего
                       ; но это моя реализация, в ней можно что-нибудь и сделать
                       ; ** надо быть чем-то функциеподобным, ведь он будет вызван
      ...] ; ...и остальные тоже нужно определить, хоть nil'ами
  (**       *****  **
    **     **  ** **
     **   **   ****
      ** **    ** **
       ***     **  **
                    **
   ********************
   *********************))
```

---

Ну и совсем неинтересный случай:

```clj
(comment
   **       *****  **
     **     **  ** **
      **   **   ****
       ** **    ** **
        ***     **  **
                     **
    ********************
    *********************)
```

Это `nil`. [Ну, `comment` это макрос, схлопывающийся в `nil`.](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/comment) Вот его реализация:

```clj
(defmacro comment
  "Ignores body, yields nil"
  {:added "1.0"}
  [& body]) ; после объявления списка аргументов *ничего нет*
```

Это не совсем комментарий, в привычном смысле, в форме `comment` должен быть синтаксически правильный код, иначе форма окажется некорректной и выполнение упадёт. Но этот символ вполне себе корректный Clojure-код!.. ну, без определений.

Макросами, возможно, из него можно сделать что-то интересное.

Answer (score 7):

## Perl

Данным логотипом можно немножечко напугать, если наложить его поверх perl-скрипта:

main.pl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

use Ohlabishch;
use re 'eval';

**************************************
*;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;*
*****''=~('(*****?{**'.**('[^@._['.***
***'**|~{+]**].-%@]**@**?+__'^********
***'+**,)@**+{^?[_$****}]@@,>('.******
***'^@**~**}').'})'** **);;;;;;;;;****
***;;;;***;;;;;;;;;**;;**;;;;;;;;;****
***;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; **;;;;;;;;****
***;;;;********************;;;;;;;****
***;;;;*********************;;;;;;****
***;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;****
*;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;**
**************************************
```

Ohlabishch.pm:

```
package Ohlabishch;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Filter::Simple sub { s/\*//g };

1;
```

---

### Как работает эта мешанина из символов?

**Шаг 1**. Подключаем модуль Ohlabishch, в задачи которого входит удалить все символы из исходного таким.

Без них этот код примет вид:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
''=~('(?{'.('[^@._['.
'|~{+]].-%@]@?+__'^
'+,)@+{^?[_$}]@@,>('.
'^@~}').'})' );;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; ;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

**Шаг 2**. Добавим пустую операцию `;`, которая опять же ничего не делаем. Без неё, код имеет вид (последнюю `;` оставим всё-таки):

```
''=~('(?{'.('[^@._['.
'|~{+]].-%@]@?+__'^
'+,)@+{^?[_$}]@@,>('.
'^@~}').'})' );
```

**Шаг 3**. Выполним соединения строк, там где это возможно и запишем всё в одну строку:

```
'' =~ ( '(?{' . ( '[^@._[|~{+]].-%@]@?+__' ^ '+,)@+{^?[_$}]@@,>(^@~}' ) . '})' );
```

**Шаг 4**. Рассмотрим внимательно строку:

```
'[^@._[|~{+]].-%@]@?+__' ^ '+,)@+{^?[_$}]@@,>(^@~}'
```

Несмотря на её устрашающий вид, задача у неё весьма простая, посимвольно применить операцию xor для данных двух строк. Т.е:

```
perl -E 'say "["^"+"'
p

perl -E 'say "^"^","'
r
```

и т.д. В итоге мы получим строку вида: `print "A ty smelchak!"`

**Шаг 5**. На данный момент код преобразуется в:

```
'' =~ ( '(?{' . ( 'print "A ty smelchak!"' ) . '})' );
```

**Шаг 6**. Убираем лишние скобки и символы соединения строк, таким образом получая задуманный код:

```
'' =~ ( '(?{ print "A ty smelchak!" })' );
```

Что это такое? Это просто "регулярное выражение", которое применяется к пустой строке. Само же регулярное выражение это форма `"(?{ code })"`, которая позволяет выполнять код в данном регулярном выражении. По умолчанию оно отключено, и чтобы его подключить нужно добавить в программу строку: `use re 'eval'`.

Comment: А что при этом выводится?

Comment: @VladD "A ty smelchak!"

Answer (score 6):

## C++

http://ideone.com/VpcGQz

```
int main() {

**       *****  **
 **     **  ** **
  **   **   ****
   ** **    ** **
    ***     **  **
                 **
********************
*********************

main;}
```

Answer (score 1):

## C++

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cout << R"(
**       *****  **
 **     **  ** **
  **   **   ****
   ** **    ** **
    ***     **  **
                 **
********************
*********************
)";
}
```

Comment: Хм.. строковый литерал... Хотя про `R` не знал. И подравняй хвост - он что-то съехал.