# &&&&& и прочие операторные странности

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Недавно тут пробегал вопрос о последовательностях операторов `++++` и `----`. Навеяло...

У Саттера в "Новых сложных задачах" есть забавная задачка 33 о том, сколько можно в корректном коде C++ использовать одинаковых символов того или иного оператора подряд (комментарии, препроцессор, макросы, литералы не рассматриваются).

Мой вопрос - с выходом стандарта C++11/14 изменился ли его ответ на эту задачу?

Как я понимаю, теперь последовательность `>>>>` становится бесконечной - в шаблонах теперь не требуется вставлять пробел...

Остальные операторы - вроде бы должны остаться неизменными.

Но теперь в C++ конструкция `&&` приобрела еще один смысл. В связи с этим - вопрос: *осталось ли неизменным решение Саттера с пятью `&` подряд или теперь его можно превзойти*?

Это не соревнование, но если кто-то превзойдет Саттеровские решения - будет интересно посмотреть. Для справки:
`+`,`-`,`!`,`~`,`*` - тривиальные бесконечные последовательности
`&` - пять штук
`<`,`|` - по четыре
`...` - даже не смешно :)

Да, получить два  `%%` или там  `^^` тоже просто:

```
class X
{
public:
    void operator%(int);
};
typedef void(X::*F)(int);
void operator%(F,X){}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    X x;
    &X::operator%%x;
}
```

Comment: Ещё звёздочку надо в бесконечные записать: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/520258/178988.

Comment: А, ну да, конечно. Но, кстати, У Саттера ее не было(!)

Comment: Ремарку про троеточие не понял. Но 6 точек подряд быть [может](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5625600/3240681).

Comment: @alexolut Ну, в смысле что `...` - это *не три оператора точки*. Что до шести точек - не скромничайте, интересно познакомиться :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

По моему мнению, использование новой семантики для `&&` в c++11 не позволит построить более длинную цепочку, чем у Саттера (5 символов подряд). Причина, по которой я так считаю, опирается на возможные новые контексты использования `&&`:

- указание rvalue-ссылки для типа локальной переменной:

  ```
  R&& r = makeR();
  ```
- использование универсальной ссылки в шаблонной функции:

  ```
  template<typename T>
  void f(T&& param);
  ```
- использование универсальной ссылки для локальной `auto` переменной:

  ```
  auto&& r = f(something);
  ```
- перегрузка функций-членов для rvalue/lvalue объектов:

  ```
  struct S {
      void f() & {}
      void f() && {}
  };
  ```

Во всех упомянутых контекстах `&&` используется при объявлении сущности. Указать тут больше, чем 2 `&` подряд, не представляется возможным. Компилятор будет сообщать, что нельзя сделать ссылку на ссылку. Например, для *clang*:

> ```
> 'variable' declared as a reference to a reference
> ```

Для шаблонной функции или перегруженных для rvalue/lvalue указание типа при вызове явно не требуется, а определяется из типа выражения. Т.е. `&` при вызове не используются вовсе. А если и используются, то только для явного приведения, где больше двух `&` по-прежнему нельзя указать. Например:

```
static_cast<T&&>(t);
```

При попытке указать больше - получим уже упомянутую ранее ошибку "ссылка на ссылку".

Т.о. побить рекорд Саттера для `&` появление новой семантики ссылок в c++11 не позволяет.

Comment: А обещанные шесть точек? :)

Comment: @Harry может чуть позже, если никто не напишет :) Но, вообще, всё, что нужно есть по ссылке из комментария.

Answer (score 5):

Шесть точек `......`. На основании [сообщения](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5625600/3240681) с enSO.

Имеем код:

```
template <typename T>
struct X { };

template <typename T, typename ... U>
struct X<T(U......)> { };
```

Здесь присутствует шаблон структуры `X` и частичная специализация этого шаблона для параметризации типа функцией, принимающей несколько параметров `U......` и возвращающей тип `T`.

`U......` есть то же самое, что `U...  ...` или `U..., ...`. `U...` представляет собой безымянный набор типов, переданных шаблону, а последующие `...` - сишное многоточие для обеспечения передачи переменного количества параметров. Таким образом, для инстанцирования специализации шаблона можно использовать, например, следующий код:

```
X<int(double, char, ...)> x;
```

`x` параметрирован функцией, возвращающей `int` и принимающей как минимум 2
параметра: один - типа `double`, второй - типа `char`, после может быть
использовано любое количество дополнительных параметров (как в `printf`), для доступа к которым надо использовать функции из заголовочного файла [`<cstdarg>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/).

При использовании варианта без явной запятой между троеточиями *clang* выдает, поясняющее суть, [предупреждение](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/EdxfsaLROQQM5KKB):

> ```
> '...' in this location creates a C-style varargs function [-Wambiguous-ellipsis]
> ```